# My android project is not reacting to any changes in the code of .java files

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

My android project had so far been working perfectly fine, just as expected. Now, however, my app does not react to *major* changes in code at all. I have no idea how, why or when exactly it happened, but one of my .java activity files was basically reverted to a default state and all of the code I had written was removed, only the boiler plate code is there now, with the minimum includes and the onCreate().

```
package com.example.treasurehunt;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FindGame extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Toast.makeText(this, "FindGame was changed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

That activity works with Firebase to populate a listView with entries from the database. Without the code in it, that listView should be completely empty, but even when I build the app again (which should give an error but it doesn't) and run it, the activity works as normal. I changed the code in the onCreate() to include a Log.i message, and it doesn't show up in the Logcat. I then made it so it shows a Toast in the onCreate(), and that doesn't show up either, so it just doesn't change as the code does, which is super weird.

[image: What the activity normally looks like]

I went into the project directory and opened the FindGame.CLASS file in Notepad++ to see if it maybe had the old, complete version of the code and it didn't. I also checked the local history and the old, correct version isn't there. I'm baffled and don't understand how the android app can kind of ignore the contents of a .java file, or even why it would just change on it's own in the first place.

I didn't have Version Control, I know that's kind of a cardinal sin, I got arrogant and assumed something like this could never happen and that I wouldn't make other kinds of mistakes but now I'm paying for it. I have no code to show for my FindGame activity and no way to change my app, even though it works. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: did you test inavlidate cache and restart?

Comment: I did, invalidate cache and restart and then clean and rebuild, but that didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

1. Build -> Clean Project
2. Build -> Rebuild Project
3. Run the app again.

Comment: It didn't work :(